# Openpyxl with python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I wanted to open excel file on python with using this code.

```
import openpyxl
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('testfile.xlsx')
```

Error:No such file or directory: 'testfile.xlsx'

Where should I locate this file?

I am using Python2.7 on Spyder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that there is that file in the folder... Try this command to list the files in that folder just to make sure that python atleast recognizes or reads the files.

```
import os
print (os.listdir('your path'))
```

Try giving an absolute path. I mean give a leading slash which means an absolute path, or a path that starts at the root of your filesystem. No leading slash makes the path relative to your working directory.... I guess thats why it ain't working.

Lets say your file in downloads(as said in the comments)...

```
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/name/Downloads/your_file')
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand, my file is in let's say downloads than what should I do?
What exactly your code is doing?